# System Status: Error after upgrade to 5.10.0

Tags: upgrade, error, system-status

I upgraded from 4.4 to 5.10.0 (WordPress). Upgrade seemed to go fine. Now when I go to the home page for CiviCRM, I get a blank page with System Status: Error in the footer (in pink). There are no other error messages and I have no idea what the error is. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot?

Comment: Can you check browser console for any error? Also try clearing civicrn cache

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: For some reason, it now works. I think it may have been some configuration issue that was cleared up when the system restarted. Thanks for the quick reply.